# Whitening the data from the LIGO project

Tags: signal-processing

I'm following the official [LIGO tutorial](https://losc.ligo.org/s/events/GW150914/GW150914_tutorial.html) and I want to do a whitening process now. I computed FFT using `hf=Fourier[data]` then PSD using `psd=PeriodogramArray[data, Round[1/dt], 1, HannWindow]`. In next step I interpolated PSD `inter_psd=Interpolation[psd]`. In tutorial they divide `hf/(np.sqrt(interp_psd(freqs) /dt/2.))` where `freqs=np.fft.rfftfreq(Nt, dt), dt=1/4096, Nt=131072`. So, as I understand, they divide only by the ASD values for the discrete Fourier transform sample frequencies. Is this possible to obtain those freqs in some of Mathematica functions? Or is there another possibilty to whiten the data?

Comment: I have slides [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjYjvnKlqHOAhVD4IMKHQEMCQMQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmaterials.dagstuhl.de%2Ffiles%2F15%2F15251%2F15251.DanielLichtblau.Slides.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFrj9-VfyinzsO5X0SHiTjIGybw6g&sig2=O1t_IFnNUXufUxXy9sqSGg) that have an example of subtracting an estimated dominant sinusoid from data, in effect whitening, in order to get the next frequency component estimated. Not positive this will help but it looks like you are wanting to do something similar.